# Time complexity to find path from bottom-left to top-right block

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

I am confused in calculating the time complexity of one problem, please help me in that.

**Problem statement:-**

2-D matrix is given, you are at bottom-left block, and you have to go to top-right block. One constraint is given, from every point to can move only step either upwards or right direction.

How many such ways are there, prove mathematically ?

Time complexity is in polynomial or exponential form ?

**My effort :-**

If the matrix is of N*N size, then you have to move exactly 2N steps, out of which N steps is R, and remaining N steps is U.

So, if we simplify this, its a permutation and combination problem, A string is given that contains only two letters R and U, how can you arrange that ?

**Answer is**

```
( (2N) C (N) )*( (N) C (N) )*2
```

**Question**

1. Is my above logic correct? If not, please correct me.
2. Above formula is polynomial or exponential ?

Comment: Although this is more of a math question The number of ways = factorial(2N-2)/( factorial(n-1) * factorial(n-1) )

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Can you explain your formula ?

Comment: This [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/recreational-math/brain-teasers/v/path-counting-brain-teaser) from khanacademy should help you understand the problem better. (there is 3D version as well).

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct. However answer is a bit inaccurate.
The string only has letters R and U but its length is 2N-2.

The problem is to arrange 2N-2 objects such that n-1 are of 1 type and n-1 objects are of other type.

```
The number of possibilities = factorial(2N-2)/( factorial(n-1) * factorial(n-1) )
```

If you consider product of 2 numbers as O(k), then calculating the above shall have a time complexity of O(N*k).

To get an idea of the order of multiplication for various algorithms, you can visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations

EDIT: 
**This number appears in the expansion of binomial coeffecients of 2^(2n-2).
Hence we can safely say that "counting up to this number" is bounded by an exponential rate of growth, not factorial.**

Comment: As of my solution , it is Catalan number and catalan number has of exponential complexity. Where I am wrong can you tell me please !!!

Comment: @devsda You are right, the number to be calculated is a Catalan number. IMO calculation by formula is not exponential in time complexity. However, if you want to enumerate all possibilities and 'count' them upto the Catalan number, then that amounts to 'factorial' complexity.

Comment: So then in which category it would be put (exponential or polynomial) ?

Comment: @devsda As I said, if you just want to calculate this number, it is polynomial, but if you want to 'count' the number of possibilities upto the number then it is factorial time complexity.